# How do I easily and securely restrict a user of one schema in SQL Server when I need to access many objects from other schemas?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a bunch of procedures in a schema *web* that uses on various other tables, views, procedure etc. from other schema.

I want to restrict a user to these procedures in the schema *web*, but I don't want to explicitly give each of the objects from the other schemas A combination of DENYs and a GRANT. like this....

```
A combination of DENYs and a GRANT. For example:

DENY SELECT ON schema::[dbo] TO [user_name]
DENY SELECT ON schema::[other_schema] TO [user_name]
GRANT SELECT ON schema::[safe_schema] TO [user_name]
```

How to do this and and most importantly, is it safe?